# French equivalent for “really?”

Tags: interjections

In English one can say 'really?' in a conversation to show interest and to imply 'tell me more'. 
What word in French could be used for the same thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Vraiment ?
>
> C'est vrai ?
>
> T'es sérieux ?
>
> Sans blague ?
>
> ah bon ?

*hein* is not really a word, more of a sound like *huh ?*

I hear this a lot though.  Really can take on several meanings, but *Vraiment* is the closest literal translation.

Comment: shouldn't it be "vraiment?", with a "?" ?

Comment: I see many differences between the given translations, could you give some details to distinguish them and know when to use one or an other ?

Answer (score 3):

le plus courant: *vraiment ?*

un peu moins utilisé: *réellement ?*

très courant oralement: *ah bon ?*

très courant oralement, un peu dubitatif: *Non ?*

très courant oralement, peu stylé: *hein ?*

Comment: I think "Hein?" convey the idea you did not hear properly what was said and you want them to repeat, not that you want more detail.

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas I think it depends the tone. If the person is saying something very surprising, you may use "hein ?" to mean "I can't believe it !"

Comment: Ho, rigth. "*Hein ?! Oo*" then :)

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas Yeah, the "Oo" part is important for this meaning :D

Comment: @Graffito , oui, ajouté, merci.

Answer (score 3):

As already stated *Vraiment ?* is obviously the closest translation but imho slightly formal.

You'll more likely hear answers like:

- *C'est vrai ?* (is it true?)
- *Pour de vrai ?* Colloquial (for real?)
- *Sans dec'* *?* / *Sans déconner ?* Colloquial (no bullshit?)